# complex serialize class java/ no error pop up

Tags: java, serialization

When i execute the methods in the class my application crashes. please tell me whats wrong or ways to optimize this class. it creates no error messages when i run it. so i have no idea whats wrong. i have tried everything that i know and able to find out threw reviewing other work.

```js
package main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class List {

 public static void saveList(ArrayList<String> x){
  Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  DateFormat ft= new SimpleDateFormat("W-MM-yyyy");
  String fileName= ft.format(date)+ ".bin";
  ObjectOutputStream os;
  try {
   os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
   os.writeObject(loadList().addAll(x));
   os.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  
 }
 
 
 public static ArrayList<String> loadList() throws IOException{
  Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  DateFormat ft= new SimpleDateFormat("W-MM-yyyy");
  String fileName= ft.format(date)+ ".bin";
  ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<>(); 
  
  ObjectOutputStream on;
  on = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Names.bin"));
  on.writeUTF(fileName);
  on.close();
   
  ObjectInputStream or;
  try {
   or = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Names.bin"));
   String hi= new String(or.readUTF());
   or.close();
   or= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(hi));
   Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
   int in= reader.nextInt();
   while(in!= 0){
    array.add(Integer.toString(in));
    in= reader.nextInt();
   }
   reader.close();
   or.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("File Not Found");
   }
  return array;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any output that your application is doing? Are you possibly redirecting stdout/stderr? If nothing else a driver for how you are exercising these methods would be good.

Comment: List is a bad bad name for a Class, even more when you're using the java.util package

Comment: i'm trying just to save a file with different array lists. the second part is to make a new data list based on the old one.